# SqlExpress Db Is in use by system

Tags: database, system, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, localdb

I have a strange problem that is reoccurring. My app is a MVC5 application using EF code first and SQLExpress. My solution uses 4 databases - 3 of which work without a problem. The fourth database is constantly 'acquired' by 'System'. Everyday for the last week when I boot up I have a problem.

When I run the app and the DatabaseInitializer runs I get this exception :

> Cannot open database "databaseName" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'Computer\UserName'.

Weird. I read some S.O. articels about changing permision, but that smells to me. This database shouldent be in someone elses domain in the first place! The other databases work fine !

So I go about deleting the database. I get this error.

> Error deleting file 'database.mdf'. The process cannot access the file because it is being use by another process.

So I reboot and go to delete the database directly from the windows explorer.

> The action can't be completed because the file is open in System

I was finally able to delete the file by running my PC in safe mode and deleting it there. Im not sure what the cause of this is. I am running SQL express and I don't see any SQL background services running.